# Bandwidth of laser pulses

Tags: optics, laser

I am working on a practice test for my optics class.  The professor does not provide the solutions for the test.  I was just wondering if someone could tell me if I am doing this correctly because it seems kind of simple but I am unsure.

> A laser emits short pulses of duration 14.0 ps separated in time by
>   1.0 ns at a wavelength of 1 um.  From one pulse to the next, the timing of field oscillations is kept perfectly  coherent and phase
>   stable using sophisticated feedback control.
>
> What is the bandwidth of the source (in Hertz)?

I think the answer to this would be 1/t which is 1 /14 ps = 71 Ghz

I think it is just that simple but I want to know if I am wrong so I do not make that mistake on the actual test.  Also just to clarify the bandwidth of the pulse is the range of frequencies in that pulse of light right?

Comment: See for example this article: https://www.rp-photonics.com/time_bandwidth_product.html

Answer (score 1):

About 30 GHz,
[according to this.](http://www.cmxr.com/Education/TBcalculator.html)
Check "Bandwidth-limited Pulses". 
Because of Fourier transform, the product of the temporal duration and spectral width is ≈ 0.44 for Gaussian-shaped pulses. See [also this.](https://www.rp-photonics.com/bandwidth_limited_pulses.html)